# How to delete route entries from routing table using an agent in UnetStack

Tags: unetstack

In my routing protocol, I want to update the routing table dynamically at a periodic interval, as of now, I am adding route entries to the routing table from my agent, by sending the `RouteDiscoveryNtf` message to the router agent, which is similar to using `addroute` closure in the shell.

I want to know, **How I can delete the route entries. So that, I can update the routing table with new entries.** As the, `delroute`, `delroutesto`,`delroutes` closures, which works in shell, cannot be used in an agent.

Also I want to know is my approach is right for updating the routing table dynamically or is there any other better way for doing this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of UnetStack (1.4) does not define messages to delete routes, so there's no "correct" way to ask router to delete a route. Later versions might introduce messages for this. For now, you could do it in the same way as the `delroute`, `delroutes` and `delroutesto` shell functions do it, **but bear in mind that you may need to update this in later versions of UnetStack**.

The `router` agent exposes two unlisted parameters (`removeRoute` and `removeRoutesTo`) to allow deletion of routes. **These may be removed in future versions once UnetStack defines messages for this purpose.**

Code snippet showing how the 3 shell functions are implemented:

```
// remove route number n (0 based numbering)
void delroute(n) {
  router.removeRoute = n-1
}

// remote all routes in routing table
void delroutes() {
  router.removeRoute = -1
}

// remove all routes to node
void delroutesto(node) {
  router.removeRoutesTo = node
}
```

If you're implementing in Groovy, you can use pretty much the same code with `router` being the `AgentID` or the router agent. If you're implementing in Java, you'll have to send the appropriate `ParameterReq` to set these parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, and yes, I am implementing in Groovy, the same code (all 3 functions) working for me, in deleting entries, with `router` as the `AgentID`

Comment: Fantastic! Would you then mind "accepting" the answer please? Thanks.